# Can onResume be called two times with no onPause in between in the same Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've made an observation that on certain Android devices (Galaxy S8, LG, Motorola) `onResume` is being called two times in a row with no `onPause` in between. This pattern happens after `onNewIntent`. Here is the sequence of logs in a dummy app:

```
Step 1. User starts the app
11-08 09:25:58.708 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onCreate
11-08 09:25:58.896 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onStart
11-08 09:25:58.971 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onResume

Step 2. User goes to background
11-08 09:26:04.949 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onPause
11-08 09:26:05.830 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onStop

Step 3. User comes back to the app
11-08 09:26:49.470 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onNewIntent
11-08 09:26:49.507 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onStart
11-08 09:26:49.530 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onResume

Step 4: We get second on resume
11-08 09:26:55.088 [MyActivity, hashcode - 126479478] onResume
```

Does Android Framework guarantee `onPause` after each `onResume` given that the app is forcefully not killed by an OS? I always assumed it as true by default, but can’t find any reference for it in documentation.

Comment: Just an observation, but the logs suggest that the second  `onResume` is occurring about five and a half seconds after the first one. Is that consistent?

Comment: yes, I think it's somewhat consistent for all the uses cases that I can observe. At this point I'm trying to understand if that onResume is triggered by OS or by custom OS modifications by manufacturers or by me

Comment: I see. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your `onResume` override (create an empty one if necessary) and checking the stacktrace to see where it's being called from that second time?

Comment: indeed that was my plan, but this issue is super hard to reproduce. I'm mostly relying on bugsnag in this case, which in a large user base shows that this issue does occur from time to time.

If nothing else, I'll probably include stack-trace for each repeated `onResume` call to be logged in Bugsnag just to see the origin of that second call.

Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: confirmed, stack traces are identical for regular `onResume` and second consecutive `onResume` with no `onPause` in between

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Android Activity lifecycle?

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: yes :), I have checked this documentation and the closest thing I could find is: "When an interruptive event occurs, the activity enters the Paused state, and the system invokes the onPause() callback."

But this does not clearly answer my question: is onPause guaranteed after absolutely each onResume or not?